# How to find actually necessary gem set 

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

when I was created a new rails app with `rails new app_name`. I found that many gems were installed and I suspect I will not use many of them. It is possible to have a minimal set of gems when I do a `rails new`?

Thank you.

**Additional information**:
I'm concerned about this because when I push a fresh new rails app onto heroku, I realized many gems are installed, and I'm not using most of them.

Comment: You should tell which are the gems you think you'll not need.

Answer (score 0):

What ending up within your application in controlled through the "Gemfile" in your root directory. Running `bundle` / `bundle install` will install the gems and their dependencies.
But having gems available in the system doesn't mean your application will rely on them.

Further reading: http://gembundler.com/gemfile.html

Comment: Hmm. Im not sure if I've got my question answer. May I ask again: As I do a `rails new generate` to create a new rails app, I'm concerned that unnecessary gems are included in the app (as it can be seen in the `Gemfile`).

Comment: Looking into the Gemfile which you'll find when you run 'rails new' you'll see 7 gems beeing used through your Gemfile. From what I can say you'll need all of them.